# iterate through checkedListBox testing for checked - cast error

Tags: winforms, foreach, checkedlistbox

i'm trying to check each item in a checkedlistbox and do something with the item depending if it is checked or not. I've been able to just get the checked items with the indexCollection, but i'm having trouble getting all of the items, i'm getting this error 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem'

```
        foreach (ListViewItem item in checkedListBox2.Items)
        {
            if (item.Checked == true)
                //do something with item.name

            else
                //do something else with item.name
        }
```

i'm unsure why it's giving me the string cast error in the foreach line. How can I accomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you allow a checkbox to have the Indeterminate state then you should use the [GetItemCheckState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.getitemcheckstate%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method to retrieve the state of a check box

```
for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox2.Items.Count; i++) 
{
     CheckState st = checkedListBox2.GetItemCheckState(checkedListBox2.Items.IndexOf(i));
     if(st == CheckState.Checked)
        ....
     else if(st == CheckState.Unchecked)
        ....
     else
        ... // inderminate
}
```

otherwise is enough to call [GetItemChecked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.getitemchecked%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) that return a true/false value (true also for the indeterminate state)

Answer (score 2):

CheckedListBox.Items holds the collection of `objects`, not the collection of `ListViewItem`

You can check it this way

```
        for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox2.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (checkedListBox2.GetItemChecked(i))
            {
                //do something with checkedListBox2.Items[i]
            }
            else
            {
                //do something else with checkedListBox2.Items[i]
            }
        }
```